# Provable zero-free region for any entire function that analytically is similar to zeta(s)

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there an entire function $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb C$ such that for some $\delta>0$:

1. $f(z)$ is bounded when $\Re z>1+\delta$
2. $f(z)$ is unbounded when $\Re z=1$
3. $f(z)$ grows polynomially in vertical strips, ie for all $\sigma$ there is $C_\sigma$ so that $|f(\sigma+i t)|\ll|t|^{C_\sigma}$
4. $f(z)$ does not vanish when $\Re z>\frac12$ (provably!).

Conjecturally there is a very rich family: $L$-functions, but (4) is unproven.

If you drop (2), $1+e^{-z}$ works, or $\zeta(1/2+i t)$, or Wang zeta functions

If you drop (3), the Selberg zeta functions works, or $\exp(L(s))$

Edit: Note that $\zeta(s)$ is not entire so you can instead look at $\zeta(s)(s-1)/(s+2)$ or change the question to allow finitely many singularities, where the bounds are taken away from the singularities.

Comment: Zeta-function is not entire: it has a pole. 

Comment: Also the Selberg Zeta function has zeros with $[1/2,1]$!

Comment: for example at $s=1$ always, but sure there are only finitely many of these. Why are you looking for such a function?

Comment: Zeta is not entire, but you can look at any non-polar L-function and you can subtract off the polar parts. ie: $zeta(s)+\frac1{1-s}$.
Isn't there a selberg zeta function that, once you compensate for the scattering matrix, you morally know where the zeros are?  I heard it given as an example but haven't worked it out firsthand.  You can also remove finitely many zeros by dividing by a polynomial.  A simpler example in my case is $\exp(L(s))$.

Comment: I'm looking for such a function in order to verify that there's no fundamental analytic obstruction to all of GRH.  Assuming GRH, these $L$ functions would start to behave very bizarrely at around height $e^{e^{e^3}}}$, based on things like Schottky's Theorem and Iwic's paper on reasons to doubt RH

Comment: Also $\zeta(s)-(s-1)^{-1}$  have zeros on $\sigma>1/2$, example:
one near  0.50000132378059385590 + 99997.458357552926821 I. We must recongize that until now we can not give
any example of an entire (or even meromorphic with a finite number of poles) function satisfying conditions (1), (2), (3) and (4).

Comment: Oops, you're right, Juan.  The right way to get rid of the pole Of zeta is to multiply by $(s-1)/(s+2)$, which will also work in general, pairing up poles and zeros

Comment: @Ralph: How would $L$-functions behave bizarrely under GRH, at around height e^{e^{e^3}}}?

Comment: $e^{e^{e^3}}\approx 2\times 10^{229\,520\,860}$

Comment: Functions from the unit disk that are bounded in the center and very large in the disc start to behave as rigidly as entire functions.  Take Schottky's Theorem for example, which states that a holomorphic function $\mathbb D\rightarrow\mathbb C\backslash\{0,1\}$ must be bounded by an explicit function of $|z|$ and $|f(0)|$
So taking a disk centered at $5/4+iT$ with radius $1/2$ containing sufficiently large values, L on the disk must somewhere equal 1 and must in fact equal any bounded (above and below) function you can write down.
You can also use this to find zeros of lin.comb of L functions

Comment: @Ralph Furmaniak. 
But I expect that  any disk with center at 5/4+i T with radius 1
and T big enough contains points with zeta(s)=1. You have not 
explained the criptic form of your constant $e^{e^{e^3}}$. 
I would like to know the reason of this election. 

This said I am not so sure that there is a function satisfying your 
conditions. All my examples ends with sup beta = sigma limit where the function is not bounded if beta + i gamma are the zeros.
Of course when one is in mood of being skeptical.

Comment: I also would like to know where this constant comes from. Note that if there exists a function $f$ satisfying your conditions, then it can be uniformly approximated on any compact subset of the strip $\{1/2<\operatorname{Re}s<1\}$ by some vertical translate of the Riemann zeta function, by Voronin's Universality theorem : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality

Hence it is true that the zeta functions, in some sense, contain all possible behaviors of non-vanishing holomorphic functions.

Comment: @Ralph: What's wrong with $\zeta(s)$ taking the value 1 off the critical line?

Comment: The functions like that do exist, of course, but the first construction that comes to mind is just totally shameless cheating all the way through. Are you sure you do not want to tighten the requirements significantly to make it really worth the bounty? 

Comment: There's plenty more hypotheses that can be added, but I'm very interested in even a cheating solution, especially since the bounty expires in 2 days and there's been no ideas.

For later, one may want $f(\sigma+i t)$ to have a tight min and max of $1-\sigma$ and $(1-\sigma)^{-1}$ respectively when $\sigma>1$.  You may want large values on the 1-line to have positive density.  You may want the mean square to exist on vertical lines between 1/2 and 1 

Comment: If I would add one condition, I would add that the function have 
of the order of T*log T zeros  on the line sigma = 1/2 in 
the segment 0 < t < T. 
But even without this I do not know any solution. 
I would like to see the ones "shameless cheating all the way through" 

Comment: OK, I'll post it today but let me get home first. :) Just promise not to accept or upvote because to get 100 rep points for shameless cheating is, well, a shame...

Comment: @Juan, right: having on the order of $T\log T$ zeros would be good.  This is close to the statement of polynomial growth.  It would be good to add that the function itself should be bounded as $|f(z)|\lt\lt|z|^{d|z|}Q^|z|$ for some $d$ and $Q$

Comment: OK, edit the requirements then. You know now what kind of construction you do NOT want :).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, shameless cheating, as promised.

Part 1. Let's start with something.

We need a function bounded in $\Re z>1$ and growing not too fast on each vertical line whose zeroes are somewhere on the left. The first thing that comes to mind is $1$. No zeroes anywhere in sight, beautiful control on vertical lines. All that is lacking is the unboundedness on $\Re z=1$.

Part 2. Push it up!

We now want to add some bumps on the uneventful road $\Re z=1$. It is natural to add one bump a time. We have two options for bumping: addition and multiplication. Since we want to control the zeroes without trouble, we'll use multiplication. So, we'll be looking for an infinite product.

Part 3. A tiny little bump.

Take some entire function $g$ bounded by $1$ in the right half-plane, tending to $0$ at infinity in any right half-plane, and attaining its maximum of absolute value in $\Re z\ge 1$ at $1$, where it is real and positive. Denote $g(1)=a>0$. The exact choice doesn't matter.  I'll take $g(z)=\frac{1-e^{-z}}{z}$. Put $F(z)=1+g(z)$. Now the ride along the line $\Re z=1$ is not that smooth anymore: you have to ascend to a small hill at $1$. However, at infinity everything levels to $1$ uniformly in any right half-plane. Also, if there are any zeroes, they all have non-positive real parts.

Part 4. Amplify the bump (being naive and fair)

Just raise $F$ to a high power $N$. You'll get as huge bump as you want. The problem is that it also becomes huge well to the right of $1$.

Part 5. Discriminate against numbers with the large real part.

Replace $g(z)$ by $g(z)e^{-n^2z}$. Of course the value at $1$ will suffer enormously, but everything with real part greater than $1$ will suffer much more (which is the whole point of any true discrimination).

Part 6: Amplify with discrimination.

Raise $F(z)=1+g(z)e^{-nz}$ to the power $N$. We'll get $(1+ae^{-n^2})^N$ at $1$ but only at most $(1+ae^{-n^2-2n})^N$ for $\Re z>1+\frac 2{n}$. Choose $N\approx a^{-1}e^{n^2+n}$. We'll get about $e^{n}$ at $1$ and at most $1+2e^{-n}$ to the right of $1+\frac 2n$. Now it is quite a bump, and it is next to invisible just a tiny bit to the right of $1$.

Part 7: Ship it up the line to satisfy the local regulations.

Replace $F(z)^N$ with $F(z-iy_n)^N$ with large $y_n$ to satisfy the polynomial growth restriction in $\Re z>-n$: let's even make $|F(z)^N-1|<2^{-n}(1+|z|)^{2^{-n}}$ in $\Re z>-n$. Remember that though our bump function is huge, it is still bounded in any right half plane and levels to $1$ at infinity there. We also have $|F(z)|^N\le 1+2e^{-n}$ when $\Re z>1+\frac 2n$ regardless of the shipment.

Part 8. Put the production and shipment of bumps on the conveyor belt with $n=1,2,3,...$, and enjoy the product.

Of course, this is as shameless, abominable, and mostly illegal as any manufacturing under loose government regulations. Every loophole that could be exploited in the formulation of the problem has been exploited. So, please, do not accept or upvote. Instead, think of how to tighten the regulations to force someone to do honest work. :)

Comment: Sorry, but reading the last paragraph put a smile on my face, and compelled me to first actually read the answer, and then upvote you despite your request.

Comment: That is indeed an answer and fits all of my requirements.  The one thing I should have perhaps added is that the function should be order 1 in the sense of growing like $exp(z^{1+\epsilon})$, so that it has a nice Hadamard Product and can be analyzed in terms of its zeros.

Now I need to understand how we can make your function look, in particular the growth rate as a whole.  The zeros of $F(z)$ are near the 0 axis but moving away at a rate of $\log T$.  Regardless of the $y_n$ there will be infinitely many in horizontal strips, Lthough the exact choice of $y_n$ will effect the density

Comment: Growth rate as a whole is fine if you measure it just with $e^|z|^{1+\epsilon}$: each factor is merely exponential in $|z|$ (without $\varepsilon$), so shipping it even further up does the job. The location of zeroes, on the other hand, is very far from the one you want to see. You may want to elaborate on that a bit. There are some other features that you may want to think of before formalizing the next challenge, so take your time :). 

Comment: Manufacturing under loose government regulation is not a priori entirely bad, even if it is shameless, abominable, and mostly illegal :-)

Comment: @Ralph @fedja I have upvoted the solution. I do not see anything illegal. Or do you think anything not relevant to RH is illegal? Of course the example have too many zeros, and with very large multiplicity. I think the solution must be accepted and deserves the bounty. And still I would like to see a solution with the number of zeros rho = beta + i gamma with -T < t < T bounded by C T log T. Perhaps in the line.

Comment: There's a type of argument one may pursue to move the zeros to a line.  Suppose you have a nice function with given zeros on a line, nice in the sense of having a Hadamard Product.  Then by taking the logarithmic derivative you can express the $f'(z)/f(z)$ as a sum of $\frac1{z-t}$ where $t$ ranges over the zeros.  This is an integral of $\frac1{z-t}$ with respect to a discrete measure.  But any function decaying to the right and $L^2$ on vertical lines can be expressed as such an integral with a continuous measure, by Cauchy integral formula.  Pick a discrete measure that approximates this.

Comment: Thank you fedja for the solution, it is exactly what was requested.  And thanks to everyone else who commented; it is great to see interest in this question and I hope this is just the beginning.

What makes the above solution "easy" is that the zeros can escape to the left.  This is closely tied to how we don't dictate growth rate to the left.  This makes a big difference.  For example, knowing the growth rate between 1.5 and 2, and between -0.5 and -1 allows you to prove that the gaps between zeros is at most $1/\log_3(T)$ even if the zeros have complex powers, so end up as singularities.