# Numerical coincidence for the first Riemann zero

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Is there any heuristic explanation for why the imaginary part of the first nontrivial Riemann zero, $\gamma_1\approx 14.134725$, should be so close to $\pi/2$ modulo $2\pi$?  *Mathematica* gives `Mod[Im[ZetaZero[1]], 2 Pi]/(Pi/2) // N`
as $0.998446$.

---

Edit:  I'm not interested in 'higher' approximations to $\gamma_1$, nor in general $\gamma_n$.  My question is motivated by a phenomenon that arises in at least three [edit: four] different contexts where a zero of $\zeta(s)$ (or related) is on the critical line precisely because some other expression is purely imaginary, and thus $\cos(\arg)=0$.

One example is that the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line are the same as the points where the contour $\text{Re}(\eta(s))=0$ crosses the critical line, for $\eta(s)=\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta^\prime(s)$.  See for example Zhang's paper ["On the zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ near the critical line"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-110/issue-3/On-the-zeros-of-zetas-near-the-critical-line/10.1215/S0012-7094-01-11034-X.short).

Another occurs in the Deuring-Heilbronn phenomenon: Write the Fourier expansion of the Epstein zeta function of a binary quadratic form of discriminant $-d<0$ as $T(s)+T(1-s)+U(s)$, where $T(s)+T(1-s)$ is the constant term and $U(s)$ has all the remaining terms.  In the presence of a Siegel zero, $U(s)$ is small and $|T(s)|>|T(1-s)|$ for $\sigma>1/2$, while on the critical line $T(1/2+it)+T(1/2-it)=0$ when the real part of $T(1/2+it)=0$.

For the third, see my answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287148/for-which-functions-is-the-generalized-riemann-hypothesis-known/287339#287339).

Paul Garrett's comment below reminds me a fourth example, due to (if I recall correctly) Polya.  We have
$
\Xi(t)=2\int_0^\infty \Phi(u)\cos(ut)\, dt,
$
where

$\Phi(u)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n^4\pi^2 e^{9u}-3n^2\pi e^{5u})\exp(-n^2\pi e^{2u}).
$

Because of the double exponential, the series converges extremely rapidly, and so Polya investigated the approximation by the $n=1$ term, replacing the exponential by $\cosh$ to get an even function of $u$.  The integral has a closed form in terms of K-Bessel functions, leading to
$
\Xi^*(t)=\pi^2(K_{9/4+it/2}(2\pi)+K_{9/4-it/2}(2\pi))
$
which has real zeros and the same asymptotic count of zeros as $\Xi(t)$.  But $\Xi^*$ does not model the low lying zeros: The first two occurrences of the real part of $K_{9/4+it/2}(2\pi)$ being zero are at $t=8.99281$ and at $t=19.0654$.  Hejhal later generalized this in "On a result of G. Polya concerning the Riemann $\xi$-function",
J. Analyse Math. 55 (1990), pp. 59-95.

Comment: $\gamma_1\approx 9\pi/2$ is put into some context at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190080/87355 ; a more accurate representation given there is $$\gamma_1\approx 7 \pi -\log \left(\tfrac{7}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (7 \pi )}+\tfrac{5}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (5 \pi )}+\tfrac{3}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2} (3 \pi )}+e^{\frac{5 \pi }{2}}+2 \pi \right)$$ accurate to 9 decimal places...

Comment: Just a thought: there's Polya's "near miss" idea... There's an oldish paper of D. Hejhal about it, which you surely know.

Comment: @paulgarrett: Stopple may know of this paper, but less familiar folks like me surely don't. Can you give more information that might help identify it?

Comment: @AnuragSahay see edit to question

Comment: Its hard to imagine any heuristic analysis of $\gamma_1$ that didn’t also say something about $\gamma_2$ etc., so in the absence of any similar numerical observations regarding the next few zeroes, I would attribute this coincidence to the law of small numbers.